# Large size CSV file upload

Tags: php, csv, xls

I want to know how to upload and retreive data from a large CSV or XLS file using PHP. Are there any available PHP libraries?

I tried using the code mentioned below but it is taking a large amount of time to upload. Is the only way it can be done by using cron, or is there another method?

```
$file=fopen(base_url()."/xml/sample.csv","r");
while(! feof($file))
{
    pr(fgetcsv($file));
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Uploading a large file? Parsing a  large file? (not that you mention anything other than uploading)

Comment: I just need to get all the datas in the csv file in normal it is taking lots of time

Comment: Get it where? What are you doing with it? Putting it in a database? Displaying it? Building a giant array in PHP? Saving it on your webserver? And answers will vary for specific formats like CSV, XLS, ONIX because they're all total different formats.

Comment: Putting it in a database

Comment: So I guess reading CSV is not problem but writing it to database? Lot of insert takes lot of time, you may also need to use transactions

Comment: Can you please give me any reference for it??

Comment: For loading a CSV file to a database (assuming MySQL, because you haven't bothered to mention), use [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html).... don't try to do it in PHP

Comment: And while you have now posted a tiny snippet of code.... all the real work is being don in the `pr()` function that you haven't shown

Comment: No i have just created a separate function for <pre><?php print_r($file) ?></pre>

Answer (score 1):

One way of running the script this seems to be the best way

```
$this->db->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".base_url()."/xml/sample.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES");
```

The alternate way of running the script is

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("ptt.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
if($row == 1){ $row++; continue; }
$num = count($data);
           $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    if(strpos($data[$c], 'Finished') !== false) {
    $c++;
echo "<TR> <TD nowrap>" . $data[$c] . "</ TD>"; }
    Else{
        echo "<TD nowrap>" .  $data[$c] . "</ TD>";
        }
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);

$no = 0;
//validate whether uploaded file is a csv file
$csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
//$csvMimes = array('application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv');
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $csvMimes)) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        //open uploaded csv file with read only mode
        $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
        //skip first line
        fgetcsv($csvFile);
        //parse data from csv file line by line
        while (($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE) {
            if ($line[0] != '') {
                //check whether member already exists in database with same email
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `parts_master` WHERE PART_NUM = '$line[1]'";
                $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);

                if ($num != 0) {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
                    $row_id = $row['id'];
                    $sql2 = "UPDATE `parts_master` SET ROOT_PART_NUM = '$line[2]', PART_DESC = '$line[3]', MRP = '$line[4]', ISSUE_INDICATOR = '$line[5]', TAX_DESC = '$line[6]', HS_CODE = '$line[7]' WHERE id = $row_id";
                } else {
                    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `parts_master` (id, PART_NUM, ROOT_PART_NUM, PART_DESC, MRP, ISSUE_INDICATOR, TAX_DESC, HS_CODE, isdeleted) 
VALUES (NULL ,'$line[1]','$line[2]','$line[3]','$line[4]','$line[5]','$line[6]','$line[7]',0)";
                }
                $res2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                if (!$res2) {
                    $no++;
                }
            }
        }
        //close opened csv file
        fclose($csvFile);
    }
} else {
    $no++;
}
if ($no != 0) {
    echo 'error';
} else {
    echo 'success';
}
?>
```